# Custom styles in Tiny MCE with an external CSS file

Tags: functions, tinymce, css, plugin-tinymce

I have just read [an article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-custom-styles-in-wordpress-tinymce-editor--wp-24980) on how to implement custom styles to the Wordpress Tiny MCE.

To be honest I am a bit confused as to why we have to add arrays of styles to functions.php.

The problem I have is that the styles are applied as inline CSS (see the picture). This is a problem because it will render my CSS file useless, because if I change my style sheet at a later point, I will also have to edit all articles to edit the inline CSS accordingly. In other words, big

I know that I can just remove the array of styles e.g. remove `'borderLeftWidth' => '5px',` and so on... but then I will not have a preview of the styles in the Tiny MCE. So the question is: instead of getting the styles from functions.php, how can I load the styles only from an external CSS file?

[image: As you can see in the picture I get inline CSS when what I really want is external CSS]
*As you can see in the picture I get inline CSS when what I really want is external CSS*

Preferably I would like to control the styles with a CSS file.

I also know that there are a bunch of plugins that can do this out there, but I would like to keep this a part of the theme and not a plugin.

**functions.php**:

```
// Apply styles to the visual editor
add_filter('mce_css', 'tuts_mcekit_editor_style');
function tuts_mcekit_editor_style($url) {

    if ( !empty($url) )
    $url .= ',';

    // Retrieves the plugin directory URL
    // Change the path here if using different directories
    $url .= trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()) ) . '/tinymce.min.css';
    return $url;
}

// Add "Styles" drop-down
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'tuts_mce_editor_buttons' );
function tuts_mce_editor_buttons( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}

// Add styles/classes to the "Styles" drop-down
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tuts_mce_before_init' );
function tuts_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Emphasis box',
            'block' => 'p',
            'classes' => 'emphasis-box',
            'styles' => array(
                'borderLeftWidth' => '5px',
                'borderLeftStyle' => 'solid',
                'borderLeftColor' => '#1a1a1a',
                'paddingTop' => '10px',
                'paddingRight' => '10px',
                'paddingBottom' => '10px',
                'paddingLeft' => '25px',
                'backgroundColor' => '#f9f9f9',
                'borderTopLeftRadius' => '0px',
                'borderTopRightRadius' => '5px',
                'borderBottomRightRadius' => '5px',
                'borderBottomLeftRadius' => '0px',
                'fontWeight' => '400',
                'fontSize' => '16px',
                'color' => '#000000'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Alert box blue',
                'block' => 'section',
                'classes' => 'alertbox blue',
                'wrapper' => true
                ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Alert box yellow',
                'block' => 'section',
                'classes' => 'alertbox yellow',
                'wrapper' => true
                ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Alert box red',
                'block' => 'section',
                'classes' => 'alertbox red',
                'wrapper' => true
                ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Alert box green',
                'block' => 'section',
                'classes' => 'alertbox green',
                'wrapper' => true
                ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Alert box pink',
                'block' => 'section',
                'classes' => 'alertbox pink',
                'wrapper' => true
                )

    );

    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    return $settings;
}

// Learn TinyMCE style format options at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats
 // Add custom stylesheet to the website front-end with hook 'wp_enqueue_scripts'
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tuts_mcekit_editor_enqueue');

// Enqueue stylesheet, if it exists.
function tuts_mcekit_editor_enqueue() {
  $StyleUrl = plugin_dir_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()).'tinymce.min.css'; // Customstyle.css is relative to the current file
  wp_enqueue_style( 'myCustomStyles', $StyleUrl );
}
```

**tinymce.min.css:**

```
.emphasis-box {
    border-left: 5px solid #1a1a1a;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The path to the CSS file `tinymce.min.css` was incorrect. The solution was to change:

`$url .= trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()) ) . '/tinymce.min.css';`

to:

`$StyleUrl = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style-sheets/tinymce.min.css';`

I also had to change:

`$StyleUrl = plugin_dir_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()).'tinymce.min.css';`

to:

`$StyleUrl = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style-sheets/tinymce.min.css';`

Now all I had to do was to remove the styles array so the complete code is:

```
// Apply styles to the visual editor
add_filter('mce_css', 'tuts_mcekit_editor_style');
function tuts_mcekit_editor_style($url) {

    if ( !empty($url) )
    $url .= ',';

    // Retrieves the plugin directory URL
    // Change the path here if using different directories
    $url .= trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style-sheets/tinymce.min.css';
    return $url;
}

// Add "Styles" drop-down
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'tuts_mce_editor_buttons' );
function tuts_mce_editor_buttons( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}

// Add styles/classes to the "Styles" drop-down
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tuts_mce_before_init' );
function tuts_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    $style_formats = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Emphasis box',
        'block' => 'p',
        'classes' => 'emphasis-box'
        ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Alert box blue',
        'block' => 'section',
        'classes' => 'alertbox blue',
        'wrapper' => true
        ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Alert box yellow',
        'block' => 'section',
        'classes' => 'alertbox yellow',
        'wrapper' => true
        ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Alert box red',
        'block' => 'section',
        'classes' => 'alertbox red',
        'wrapper' => true
        ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Alert box green',
        'block' => 'section',
        'classes' => 'alertbox green',
        'wrapper' => true
        ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Alert box pink',
        'block' => 'section',
        'classes' => 'alertbox pink',
        'wrapper' => true
        )
    );

    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    return $settings;
}

// Learn TinyMCE style format options at http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats
 // Add custom stylesheet to the website front-end with hook 'wp_enqueue_scripts'
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tuts_mcekit_editor_enqueue');

// Enqueue stylesheet, if it exists.
function tuts_mcekit_editor_enqueue() {
$StyleUrl = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style-sheets/tinymce.min.css'; // Customstyle.css is relative to the current file
wp_enqueue_style( 'myCustomStyles', $StyleUrl );
}
```